Drag and Drop only uploads via select
I found a pen  here that i tried to implement into my form. After so many tries and  i realised that It only uploads images via select files option only. If i try drag and drop files are not sent to my php code, but if i use it an a select files i get file on the server side
I am not very good in js, kindly assist?
below is my php code to upload files into the db
PHP
if($_POST){
if(isset($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) && $_FILES['files']['size'][0] != 0 && $_FILES['files']['error'][0] == 0) 
        {
         $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
         for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) { 
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $new_filename = time().$i.'.'.$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], '../assets/field-photos/'.$new_filename);   
            $allfiles[] = $new_filename;
         }
         $uploaded_img = implode(',',$allfiles);
        }
        else{
            $uploaded_img = '';
        }

        var_dump($uploaded_img);

        }

Here is the html form
<form action="add-products.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <input type="text" name="product">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="text" name="address">

  <label for="photo">UPLOAD Photos</label>
  <div id="drop-area">
    <div class="my-form-file ">

      <input type="file"  name="files[]" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
      <label class="button" for="fileElem"><i class="fe fe-upload fe-24 "></i> Select or drag & drop files</label>
    </div>
    <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
    <div id="gallery" /></div>
  </div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Here is the js as code
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)   
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}

let uploadProgress = []
let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  console.debug('update', fileNumber, percent, total)
  progressBar.value = total
}

function handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(uploadFile)
  files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}

function uploadFile(file, i) {
  var url = 'add-products.php'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var formData = new FormData()
   xhr.open('POST', url, true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    }
    else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
      // Error. Inform the user
    }
  })

  formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
  formData.append('file', file)
  xhr.send(formData)
}


Apart from the multiple photo files (on select or drag-and-drop), you also have "name", "lastname", "product", "city" and "address" in your form  - Please let us know what would you like to do with the above 5 data fields when the user submits the form ?

@KenLee the rest is being sent to the php file only the multiple photo files are not being sent

In order to submit both the textual form data (name, address, etc) and the multiple files (either by drag-and-drop or multiple select), you can process all the data by formData.append
So the trick is

Allow users to add files either by drag-and-drop or multiple select (I have used upload as upload folder, you may change it according to your preference, just make sure that the upload folder is writable by the system otherwise upload will fail)
Allow the above (1) operations to repeat unlimited number of times
Allow user to input other textual data (name, address, etc)
When user clicks "Submit Data", use ajax to process all the above

Since I do not know how do you use the textual data, I have demonstrated the effect by sending an email out with all the data in the message body of the mail
So, use the following HTML
<script>

// declare necessary arrays

allfiles = [];
myfile=[];
xfile=[];
xfilename=[];


// initialize / clear all past array data below

allfiles.length = 0;
myfile.length = 0;
xfile.length = 0;
xfilename.length = 0;

var init=0; 
var init2=0;

var formData = new FormData();

</script>    


<table border=0>
<tr><td>Name: <td><input type="text" name="name" id=name>
<tr><td>Lastname: <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id=lastname>
<tr><td>Product: <td><input type="text" name="product" id=product>
<tr><td>City: <td><input type="text" name="city" id=city>
<tr><td>Address: <td><input type="text" name="address" id=address>
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=button onclick="javascript:uploadFile0();" value="Submit Data">
</table>

<br>
<div id="drop-area">
<p>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</p>
    <input type="file"  id="fileElem" multiple  accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
    <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label>
  <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>
  <div id="gallery" /></div>

</div>

<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #369;
}
.note {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #333;
  text-align: justify;
}
#drop-area {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 480px;
//  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
#drop-area.highlight {
  border-color: purple;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.my-form {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#gallery {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#gallery img {
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
#fileElem {
  display: none;
}

</style>


<script>
    // ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
let dropArea = document.getElementById("drop-area")

// Prevent default drag behaviors
;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)   
  document.body.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
})

// Highlight drop area when item is dragged over it
;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
})

;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
})

// Handle dropped files
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

function preventDefaults (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function highlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
}

function unhighlight(e) {
  dropArea.classList.remove('active')
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  var dt = e.dataTransfer
  var files = dt.files

  handleFiles(files)
}

let uploadProgress = []

let progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar')

function initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  progressBar.value = 0
  uploadProgress = []

  for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    uploadProgress.push(0)
  }


}

function updateProgress(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  progressBar.value = total
  progressBar.value = 100;
}


function updateProgresscompleted(fileNumber, percent) {
  uploadProgress[fileNumber] = percent
  let total = uploadProgress.reduce((tot, curr) => tot + curr, 0) / uploadProgress.length
  progressBar.value = 100;
}

function handleFiles(files) {

files = [...files]

initializeProgress(files.length)
files.forEach(previewFile)


for(i=0; i < files.length; i++ ) {

allfiles.push(files[i].name);

xfile[init]=files[i];
xfilename[init]=files[i].name;

init++;

}

}



function previewFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = reader.result
    document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img)
  }
}



function uploadFile0()
{

  for(i=0; i < init; i++ ) {
      init2=i;
      uploadFile1();
    }

}


function uploadFile1() {

  var url = './add-products.php'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('POST', url, true)
 xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

 xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
   updateProgress(init2, (init2 * 100.0 / init) || 100)
 })

  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

   updateProgresscompleted();

    var response = xhr.responseText;
    // the above is return data from ajax call

    }
    else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {

      // Error. Inform the user
      alert("Upload Error!");

    }
  })


formData.append('myfile', xfile[init2], xfilename[init2]);
formData.append('init', init2);
formData.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
formData.append('lastname', document.getElementById('lastname').value);
formData.append('product', document.getElementById('product').value);
formData.append('city', document.getElementById('city').value);
formData.append('address', document.getElementById('address').value);


  xhr.send(formData)
}

</script>


and use the following PHP (add-products.php)
<?php

 $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['myfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['myfile']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 $new_filename = $filename . "_". time() . '_.' . $ext;

   if (copy($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],'./upload/'.  $new_filename  ) ) { 
       echo "File Uploaded: " .  $_FILES['myfile']['name'] ; 
   }

if ($_POST["init"]==0)
{

$to = "yourname@testdomain.com";
$subject = "Stackoverflow TEST" ;

$txt = "";
$txt .= "Name:"  . $_POST["name"] . "\n";
$txt .= "LastName:"  . $_POST["lastname"] . "\n";
$txt .= "Product:"  . $_POST["product"] . "\n";
$txt .= "City:"  . $_POST["city"] . "\n";
$txt .= "Address:"  . $_POST["address"] . "\n";

$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" ;

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

}
?>


The effect will be :

Note:
(1) I have added a trick so that the PHP will only process the textual data ONCE (the 1st iteration) , because it is normal to do so as the textual data should be processed ONCE but the file uploads can be multiple
(2) In real case, I think you should consider using a variable to link the uploaded photos to the textual data (e.g. textual data saved in a db table and then use the insert_record_id to link with the uploaded photos)
